# Indic Language Support for SDK but not PhoneGap

Tags: android, sdk, internationalization, harfbuzz

I am trying to develop an app in android with Indian language support exclusively. I just want to convert my text page, on app, in any Indian language, selected by user.

For this I don't want to use `web-service` and also don't want to use `Phonegap`. I did some research and realise that rendering of Indic fonts are complex.

I heard that there is a library *"Harfbuzz"* that render Indic Fonts properly, but it supports only **NDK**.

Is there any *library* or engine for **SDK**?

Comment: +1 I would also like to know...

Comment: Your question has a lot of votes but the answers don't. I see that you are still an active member even though this is an old post. Did you ever solve your problem? Would you consider either answering your own question or my similar one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539237/supporting-complex-text-layout-with-opentype-fonts-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this page of Dr. C. Scott Ananian](http://cananian.livejournal.com/63595.html), it could be useful for what you're trying to do. He has worked with ports of [Pango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pango) (an Unicode text layout library).

Answer (score 0):

enabling mobile phones with Indian scripts has been around for quite sometime. Check this out:  **http://code.google.com/p/indic-keyboards/**

(*An open source project providing an input method which will allow the usage of Indic scripts on both Windows and Linux, using Java and Unicode.*)